# HandlebarsJs.Net linking Style Sheets/CSS

Tags: c#, html, css, handlebars.js, handlebars.net

I am trying to render CSS along with my HTML in C#.net class file as follows, but the styles are not rendering. Everything else is working fine. How shall I link the style sheets?

```
string source =
@"<html>
  <head>
  <style type=""text/css"" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="myclass">
     {{body}}
    </div>
   </div>
 </body>
 </html>";

var template = Handlebars.Compile(source);

var data = new {
    title = "My new post",
    body = "This is my first post!"
};

var result = template(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is not related to Handlebars.Net, but rather [improper usage of Itextsharp](https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net/issues/144):

> the problem is with the Itextsharp.dll we are using to render the css to the pdf file.

Comment: [Solution](https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net/issues/144#issuecomment-236098302) is to declare style in head of your source rather than external file reference.